Tensorflow ragged tensor tiling
I'm using Tensorflow 2.16.1. Ultimately, for each training sample, I need to create hidden and cell tensors for use with LSTM. Different training samples require different sized hidden/cell tensors.
My thought process was to subclass PyDataset and generate batches of integers. Each integer in a batch represents the size of the LSTM tensors.
I'm getting stuck on how to generate these tensors when I have to deal with batches. If I know the batch size, I guess maybe I can do this:
class StateLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch_size=3):
        super(StateLayer, self).__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        denom = tf.sqrt(tf.cast(4, tf.float32))
        self.state_init = tf.math.divide(tf.random.normal(shape=[1, 4]), denom)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        states = [tf.tile(self.state_init, [inputs[i], 1]) for i in range(self.batch_size)]
        return tf.ragged.stack(states)

Is this a reasonable approach? I keep thinking there must be a way to do this without batch_size, but I can't figure it out.

Your approach to subclass tf.keras.layers.Layer for generating initial states for LSTM tensors based on batch inputs is reasonable. The modification to dynamically infer the batch size ensures flexibility and compatibility with varying batch sizes during training or inference. This method allows you to generate appropriately sized initial states for each sample in a batch, accommodating the different requirements of your LSTM cells.
